# im working on a kivy project... i am using toggle buttons that are create from a function... how do i know what is selected?

Tags: python, kivy, submit, togglebutton, selectall

here is the main python file...

class MainWindow(Screen):
def Get_Trending(self):
Twitz = Trending_on_Twitter()
Tikz = Trending_on_TikTok()
ingrams = Trending_on_Instagram()

```
    Trending = Twitz + Tikz
    num = 0

    for item in Trending:
        button = ToggleButton(text=Trending[num])
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(button)
        num+=1
```

here is my kivy file...

BoxLayout:

```
        size_hint_y: .8
        orientation:"vertical"
        
        ScrollView:
            GridLayout:
                id:grid
                orientation:"vertical"
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                row_default_height:60
                cols:1
                Label:
                    id: top_area
                    text:"Trending On SocialMedia"
                    height: self.texture_size[1]
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y:.1
            orientation:"horizontal"
            Button:
                text:'Select All'
            Button:
                text:"next"
```

everything is working fine when it comes to being able to see my buttons and being able to scroll thru them... i can click them... but i added two buttons... select all and next... i just dont understand how to get the states of these buttons and when i click select all to select all... and when i click next get it to add which buttons were selected to either a list or dictionary or anything really...

thankx in advance

Answer (score 1):

num = 0
for item in Trending:
mybutton = ToggleButton(
text =Trending[num])
mybutton.bind(on_press = self.choices)
self.ids.grid.add_widget(mybutton)
num+=1

```
def choices(self,coo):
    global Hash_Tags_Selected
    #print(coo.text)
    #print(type(coo.text))
    if coo.text in Hash_Tags_Selected:
        try:
            Hash_Tags_Selected.remove(coo.text)
        except:
            pass
    else:
        try:
            Hash_Tags_Selected.append(coo.text)
        except:
            pass
    print(Hash_Tags_Selected)
```